# Построение UI/Диалоговых окон Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Нужен совет о правильном построении диалоговых окон в юнити.

**Суть:** Имеется игра в одной сцене. Все диалоговые окна (магазин, меню паузы и т.д.) работают через аниматоры. Т.е. Просто убираются и появляются на экран. Я считаю, что это не особо эффективно с точки зрения оптимизации, но не знаю как их показывать по другому, если не юзать Instantiate и Destroy, офк.
Буду рад выслушать ваши советы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете отключать и включать объекты, в том числе UI, используя `GameObject.SetActive` , например:

```
CanvasForPauseMenu.SetActive(false);
```

Кроме того, если цель оптимизация, - будет разумно отключить компоненты игровых объектов, вызывающие тяжелый код каждый ход:

```
GetComponent(HardScript).enabled = false;
```

Таким же образом целесообразно поступить с анимацией, если она не воспроизводится постоянно. (потому что анимация "обновляется" каждый ход)

Кроме того, для оптимизации целесообразно использовать разные Canvas для разных меню.
(потому что Canvas при каждом изменении перерисовывается полностью и сложность перерисовки зависит от количества элементов)